# How to view Bundle Parameter in Firebase Event Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have a unique button in 4 different fragments. These unique buttons do similar stuff in all of these fragments, but with a little tweak.

Since all of these things are similar, i log them together under the event name "unique_btn_click_event"

```
val eventName = "unique_btn_click_event"
val eventBundle = Bundle()

eventBundle.putString("fragment_name", fragmentName)
eventBundle.putString("unique_stuff_1", uniqueStuff1)
eventBundle.putString("unique_stuff_2", uniqueStuff2)
eventBundle.putString("qty_selected", quantity)

FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent(eventName, eventBundle)
```

My Objective is to measure which fragment uses the unique button the most, so that i can optimize for that and possibly deprecate others.

Although the event `unique_btn_click_event`, gets logged but i can not see the history of bundle parameter that i have logged.
I click on the **fab_actions** event:

[image]

In the next page that appears, there is no place where i can view these bundles, even by number of count.

The closest i get is: **StreamView** : Which is designed to show only real time bundle data.
Real time is cool, but it can not be used to make quality decision.

I click on Stream View.

[image]

I click on **Trending** then **Events**

[image]

I see a list of realtime bundle log data.

[image]

How can i view action count of log history.

How can i nest events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to see your <strike>event parameters</strike> custom metrics on the Firebase Analytics Dashboard, you need to add them in your events. This Link will give you the steps you need to follow to add the <strike>event parameters</strike> custom metrics: [Add Custom Dimensions and metrics in Firebase Analytics Reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en)

To summarize the steps:

1. Go to **Custom Definitions** menu under **Analytics** section on the Firebase Analytics dashboard
2. Here, you will see 2 tabs: **Custom dimensions** and **Custom metrics**. Just to give an overview, custom dimensions are similar to user properties and custom metrics are similar to event parameters if you have worked with Firebase Analytics before. What has changed is that Firebase has now added a filter called **Scope** inside custom definitions and metrics that will determine whether to use user properties or event parameters to track the data.
3. Select **Custom metrics** if you want to work only with event parameters (as of the time of this writing). If you want to work with user properties, then select **Custom dimensions** as here you can select both scopes.
4. For adding new user properties/event parameters, click on **Create custom dimensions** (if you have selected *Custom definitions*) or **Create custom metrics** (if you have selected *Custom metrics*).
5. In the next window, enter your **Dimension/Metric name** (depending on what you have selected in the previous step), **Description**, **Scope** (only available for *Custom dimensions*).
6. If the scope is **Event**, then you can only set **Event parameter** and if the scope is **User**, then you only select **User property**. In our case, we have to work with event parameters so the scope should be **Event**.
7. If you have created a custom metric, then you will also get an option to set the **Unit of measurement**. As of now, we have the following options:

   - Standard (No Unit)
   - Currency
   - Distance (Feet, Miles, Meters, Kilometers)
   - Time (Milliseconds, Seconds, Minutes, Hours)
8. If you have already added user properties and event parameters before, then you can select those from the dropdown list. Otherwise, you can type your own user property/event parameter that you will use in the future.
9. Once Done, click on Save and your parameter reporting should be up and running.

In order to see the list of parameters used in your events, you need to select the Parameter Reporting tab next to the Events tab on the Analytics Dashboard.

Once you have enough tracked data, you will see the values of the event parameters on the Events page itself.

As for getting real-time event-tracking, you need to use **Debug View** to track your events in real-time. In order to enable debugging in Firebase Analytics for Android, you need to run the following commands using ADB:

**Enable Debugging in IDE**

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
```

**Enable Debugging in Debug View of Firebase Analytics**

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <your_app_package_name>
```

***NOTE:** Substitute `<your_app_package_name>` (without the <>) with the package name of your application. Example: `com.example.uniquepackagename`*

You will get the log of your event action count in the **Existing events** table in the **Events** section as mentioned above.

---

Lastly, for nesting events, I don't think Firebase Analytics currently supports that directly. However, you can use Custom User properties in your application to group the events by a User Property. User properties can be used as filters to filter events by a user property. Here is a link to get you started on User Property:
[Work with User Properties in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=ios)

After setting the user properties in your Android app, you need to add them in the Firebase Analytics dashboard as well. I have already covered this in the steps mentioned above. The name of the user property needs to be exactly the same as the name you are using in your app.

***NOTE:** Once you set a user property, it will persist in further events that you send even if you don't set it explicitly. So be careful while setting user properties as you may not need them in some events.*

I hope this helps you in your issue with events in Firebase Analytics.

---

EDIT:
It seems Google has updated the Firebase console. Now we have custom definitions (GA4) instead of user properties and inside that we have custom definitions and metrics, which is similar to the old Google Analytics tracking.

I have updated my above answer in places that were outdated. I have striken some words from my previous answer in a few places so that in case you are coming from the old Firebase Analytics implementation, you will know where the changes were made.

Please check and hope it helps.

Regards,

Aj

Comment: I did as you said, i see the charts but i am not seeing the actionName that i set. All i get is "Event Count" for the entire action. I intend to see a breakdown based on different action name

Comment: After you add the event parameters using the *Add Event Parameters* button, the event parameters should show up in the event details page. You may get a chart or a graph showing the distribution of the values and also the count for the individual values.

In order to check the event parameter values for the last 30 minutes, you can check this link: https://ibb.co/tXpYp1j

Let me know if this helps

Regards,
AJ

Comment: Here's the graph showing only event count: https://ibb.co/XY2kyVJ

Comment: Which is not different for the event count

Comment: To clarify, my button is used in different fragments. i logged the event under the same "key" but with different "value". For example, `eventBundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY, actionName)`. The actionName could differ but the event is logged under the same key. What i hope to see in the chart was a multi-line graph for different actionNames something like this https://ibb.co/6tqK65j

Comment: Generally, the event parameter values should show up along with the count and distribution on the Firebase Analytics Dashboard. I'll try things on my end as well and get back to you on this.

Comment: After doing some testing, it seems the event parameters are showing up the count and also the values. Maybe it takes some time to update in Firebase as even for me the **not set** values are showing up.   

Here is an example of the **not set** scenario: [Event Parameters Graph](https://ibb.co/JzXmbVr).  
However, if you see the past 30 minutes event details, you will find actual values of the event parameters. Here is an example: [Past 30 Minutes Event Parameters](https://ibb.co/mtJcVRF).  

I'll wait for another day to see if I get the count. Meanwhile, you can see if the values change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204481/discussion-between-aj7-and-edgedev).

Comment: So I got the event parameter values to show up in the Firebase Console. While setting the parameter value, ensure that it is set as `String` and while adding the custom parameter, make sure that it is set as **Text** and not **Number**. Here is a screenshot showing the values in Firebase Console: [Multiple Parameter Values](https://ibb.co/nbmhjbd).

Let me know if this helps

Comment: This answer is outdated. There is no "Add event parameters" button on the bottom of the Event page.

Comment: I have updated my answer in the relevant places. Please check and let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Waouh... That's so complicated for such a basic feature... Immediate on most of other analytics platforms. Why not just displaying all event values when clicking on an event in the dashboard ??? Please Google, fix this.