# Contents of Bundle in Firebase Analytics Event not showing in dashboard

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I have the same issue as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233496/how-to-view-bundle-parameter-in-firebase-event-analytics) but the answer is outdated and seems to be incorrect. It refers to a button "Add event parameters" which is not present in the current version of firebase.

I want to view the content of the bundle for the event on my Firebase event page. Here is my event page on firebase:

[image]

I've followed [this firebase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#java_1) and here is my code:

```
    private fun sendLogging(context: Context, source: String, logMessage: String) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("LOG_MESSAGE", "$source $logMessage")
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent("PUSH_CONTENT_NOT_RECEIVED", bundle)
    }
```

The `source` and `logMessage` contain precise information about what went wrong and I need to view this. It should show up?

**EDIT:**

I went to "Custom Definitions":

[image]

And I've added the event:

[image]

I discovered that only from that moment it started collecting information. But I do not see the information that I've logged anywhere. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `LOG_MESSAGE` to the Custom Definitions as an event-scoped custom dimension is the correct direction. You can follow the "Create a custom dimension" on the "[[GA4] Custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209)" page.

GA4 limits the length of event parameter names & event parameter values. See [[GA4] Collection and configuration limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744) for more information. In your case, `LOG_MESSAGE` is the event parameter's name (limited to 40 characters), and the runtime value of `"$source $logMessage"` is the event parameter's value (limited to 100 characters).

If `"$source $logMessage"` needs to be more than 100 characters, you could make the `source` and `logMessage` separate event parameters. For example, you'd update your code to:

```
bundle.putString("LOG_MESSAGE_SOURCE", source)
bundle.putString("LOG_MESSAGE_VALUE", logMessage)
```

Then, you would register `LOG_MESSAGE_SOURCE` and `LOG_MESSAGE_VALUE` as two event-scoped custom dimensions, and each would be limited to 100 characters individually.

Thanks, 
Brett Sneed 
The Google Analytics Team

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the LOG_MESSAGE under [Custom Definitions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) as an event or user custom dimension, this now available from the menu on the left in the Analytics section.
[Custom Definitions Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euvNr.png)

Comment: I did, the events are coming in now. But now the string is not complete. It only shows the last and first 10 characters of the error message... How can I view the complete information?

Comment: since a month the string isn't coming in anymore when hovering over it. Maybe the firebase team removed this functionality?